# ASP.NET control lifecycle. Control property changes only available on next load

Tags: asp.net

I have built a pager control with various properties, for example `Start` to indicate the first record which should be rendered. This is embedded in another control which actually renders the list of records. The properties' getters and setters use ViewState to persist and retrieve the values.

The links in the pager are dynamically created during the page_load. On each link, the anchor.ServerClick delegate is wired up to a lambda that sets the Start property on the pager control.

When I debug the page, I can see that the Start property is indeed updated, but that the changed value is only available the next time I load the page, presumably persisted via the ViewState mechanism.

What this means in practice is that the embedding control doesn't see the updated values of these properties in time to render the correct list. How can I have the visitor's click update the pager properties before they get used rather than afterwards?

EDIT: adding some code

Called from the Page_Load of the main control, I have a loop that references the properties of the pager. This loop determines the items which will be displayed, and if the control properties were updated by this point, it would display the correct records, but that's not the case.

```
for (int i = pager.Start - 1 ; 
          i < queryResults.Count() && i <= (pager.Start + pager.PageSize); i++) {
```

In the pager control, also called from the Page_Load, there's code like this, that adds child controls and wires up the delegate.

```
HtmlAnchor a = new HtmlAnchor();
a.HRef = "#";
a.InnerText = page.ToString();
newStartNumber = ((page - 1) * this.PageSize) + 1;
a.Attributes["data-start"] = newStartNumber.ToString();
a.ServerClick += (sender, e) => 
      { this.Start = int.Parse(((HtmlAnchor)sender).Attributes["data-start"]); };
li.Controls.Add(a);
ul.Controls.Add(li);
```

So when these anchors are clicked, the pager's Start property is updated, but it's too late.

Comment: Could you please post your code rather than we try to figure out your code in our mind?

Comment: @Win - I've added some code. I hope this is the most relevant to the problem

Comment: does your control which does the results rendering bind its data on load ? If so, it's too early to have it benefit from the 'Start' update, and you should have the binding done in Pre_render

Comment: As jbl said, it's too late. You either need to move binding inside PreRender or call a binding method explicitly right after this.Start...

Comment: @jbl I've just tried moving the routine that renders the list into the OnPreRender event. It's still too late. It really looks as though the update isn't available until the page is loaded again

Comment: I'm starting to think that viewstate might be altogether the wrong mechanism for this.

Comment: You should post more code, on how you store and retrieve Start, and how and when you use it

Comment: As noted in the question, the pager properties such as pager.Start are "standard" properties with a getter/setter that store/retrieve from viewstate. They are used as shown in the first snippet to control the loop that renders the items. (Not sure if adding more code would make this clearer: I think probably not)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, these code parts seem ok, provided :

Your Page property looks like this :

```
public int Page
{
    get { return ViewState["Page"] == null ? 0: (int)ViewState["Page"]; }
    set { ViewState["Page"] = value; }
}
```

and this :

```
for (int i = pager.Start - 1 ; 
          i < queryResults.Count() && i <= (pager.Start + pager.PageSize); i++) {
```

is in the preRender of your parent control.

And this :

```
HtmlAnchor a = new HtmlAnchor();
a.HRef = "#";
a.InnerText = page.ToString();
newStartNumber = ((page - 1) * this.PageSize) + 1;
a.ServerClick += (sender, e) => { this.Start = newStartNumber; };
li.Controls.Add(a);
ul.Controls.Add(li);
```

is in the pageload (or init) of your pager control. (maybe you don't need the data-start attribute)

You should give Ids to your HtmlAnchors.

Comment: I think you're right about not needing data-start. I'd begun with an implementation with the lambda closing over newStartNumber, and I think it was OK, but it made debugging rather less obvious. I'm not clear on how ids on the anchors would help, though.

Comment: @DominicCronin Ids  probably won't help. That's just good practice when having dynamic controls to prevent mix-ups. For your problem. I think it is located somewhere else in your code. The code shown should work.